# Another phrase for "usually use"

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Do natives say something like:

> We **usually use** indefinite article when ...

The phrase "usually use" seems a little funny to me)

Comment: Yes, we usually use _usually use_. You could use a synonym like _normally_ or _generally_ if it sounds funny to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Usually use' repeats the 'use' sound, but that isn't really a problem, it's quite normal. Examples:

> Basically, anytime you can use ‘only’, you can usually use ‘just’ to
>   mean the same thing. (BBC English web site)
>
> We can use when to introduce a single completed event that takes place
>   in the middle of a longer activity or event. In these cases, we
>   usually use a continuous verb in the main clause to describe the
>   background event (Cambridge Dictionary)

As has been commented, you can use 'generally', 'normally', 'typically', etc.